# Re-build files in Ember-CLI without running server

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am planning on moving from "EmberJS" to the Ember-cli, though I have a small problem. Is it possible only to run file watcher instead of serving/using `ember serve` that will run local server? As I am running my PHP backend on the Google App Script I have already a local python HTTP server running in localhost:8080 I do not need another one to run in localhost:4200

If I don't run `ember serve` my local changes in development environment wont get updated. Is there a better way of doing this? Is it possible to use assets in the `app` folder when running in development environment? and use `dist` folder for staging/live environments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned [in the guide](http://www.ember-cli.com/user-guide/#using-ember-cli), you can use the `build` command with the `--watch` flag.

```
ember build --watch
```

That will keep rebuilding your changes but not actually run the server.

As for your second question:

> Is it possible to use assets in the app folder when running in development environment? and use dist folder for staging/live environments?

I don't believe so. You can change the `output-path` property in your `.ember-cli` config file, but you can't have one that's specific to a certain environment. You could always write a quick script to move the files though. :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I read the document, but somehow missed that `--watch` flag.